# if and else statement check if has class

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I cant seem to figure out whats going on here... Im kind of half asleep, really trying to get this last thing done before i go to bed lol.

My goal: Click someone, then check if it has the class, if not, then add it, then remove it once the 1 second animation is complete. Right now im getting unexpteced identifier on the 3rd line down. (removeClass)

Note: the `slamedown` class is a keyframe

```
$('#accountloginsignup h1').click(function() {
  if ($('#takeonebar').hasClass('slamdown')){
    $('#takeonebar')removeClass('slamedown');
  } else {
    $('#takeonebar').addClass('slamdown');
  }
});
```

Comment: You're missing a period in `$('#takeonebar')removeClass`

Comment: You're missing a period at `removeClass`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: And there is a typo `slamedown/slamdown`.

Comment: You definitely need some sleep.  :)

Comment: Haha, yes i do need some sleep, been up 72+ hours... didnt even know toggeClass existed though. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is for this specific purpose

From the doc

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

```
$('#accountloginsignup h1').click(function() {
    $('#takeonebar').toggleClass('slamdown');
});
```

There is a typo

```
$('#accountloginsignup h1').click(function() {
    if ($('#takeonebar').hasClass('slamdown')){
        $('#takeonebar').removeClass('slamdown');  /* missing . before removeClass */
    } else {
        $('#takeonebar').addClass('slamdown');
      }
});
```

Comment: Wow, clumsy me, now time to sleep. (: Thanks a bunch

Comment: I'll accept your answer in the morning.. i can bare wait 3 more minutes to get some sleep. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few typos:

```
$('#accountloginsignup h1').click(function() {
        if ($('#takeonebar').hasClass('slamdown')){
            $('#takeonebar').removeClass('slamdown');
        } else {
            $('#takeonebar').addClass('slamdown');
          }
        });
```

but what you really want is `$('#takeonebar').toggleClass('slamdown')`

[jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

Answer (score -1):

> this helped me while working with hasclass

$( "div" ).click(function() {

```
if ( $( this ).hasClass( "protected" ) ) {

    $( this )
        .animate({ left: -10 })
        .animate({ left: 10 })
        .animate({ left: -10 })
        .animate({ left: 10 })
        .animate({ left: 0 });

}
```

});

[reference link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-has-a-particular-class/)